# Javascript Date.now to readable format

Tags: javascript

```
Date.now();
```

I want to convert the timestamp to readable format

e.g "Fri Nov 17 2017 19:15:15 GMT+0800 (Malay Peninsula Standard Time)"

Comment: `new Date(Date.now())
`

Comment: Just do `new Date()`? Other than that, use [`momentjs`](https://momentjs.com) to format dates however you like.

Comment: Just do `Date()` or `new Date().toString()`?

Comment: Note, `Date.toString()` will not have a standard format across all browsers and other methods like `.toLocaleDateString()` or `.toDateString()` are not supported by everyone. Best approach would be to have your own function that returns your required format

Comment: As @KarlReid mention momentjs is an option, but if parts of your app will manipulate dates (add/sub days) then check https://date-fns.org/ instead momentjs. Date-fns do not mutate passed object

Answer (score 45):

```js
var date = new Date();
console.log(date.toLocaleDateString());
console.log(date.toDateString());
console.log(date.toLocaleString());
console.log(date.toUTCString());
console.log(date.toISOString());
```

Choose your method from here:
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date

Comment: Also [date.toISOString()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/toISOString)

Answer (score 13):

You could do these following statements

```js
let newDate = new Date();
console.log(`${newDate.toDateString()} ${newDate.toTimeString()}`);
```

Comment: `new Date(Date.now())` returns the same as `new Date()`.

Answer (score 4):

From the answers above, we can also do it in one line. As below,

```js
var dateString = new Date().toDateString();
console.log(dateString, '\n');
var dateString = new Date().toLocaleDateString();
console.log(dateString, '\n');
var dateString = new Date().toGMTString();
console.log(dateString, '\n');
```

Answer (score 3):

You can pass the value you get from `Date.now()` to `new Date()` this will give you the time in readable format.

For example:

```
let timestamp = Date.now();
console.log(new Date(timestamp))
```

Answer (score 2):

Just new Date();

```js
document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = Date();
```

```html
<p id="demo"></p>
```